# Twisting cochains in non-unital settings

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm reading chapter 2  of Loday and Vallette's book: *Algebraic operads*. My question is about how to translate some results in augmented settings into non unital settings.

Let $k$ be a field of charateristic zero. Let $aDG$ be the category of augmented dg algebra (positively graded) , let $CoAlg$ be the category of connected dg coalgebras (positively graded), i.e coaugmented dg coalgebras such that each $C\in CoAlg$ is the union of the kernels of the maps
$$
C\to C^{\otimes n}\to (C/k)^{\otimes n}\quad n\geq 2
$$
wich are the compositions of the canonical projection with the iterated comultiplications on $C$. Denote with $B$ the bar construction and with $\Omega$ the cobar construction. Then there is an adjuntion 
$$
Hom_{aDG}(\Omega C, A)\cong TW(C,A)\cong Hom_{Coalg}(C, BA)
$$
I wonder if it is possible write down the above adjunction into non unital settings. More precisely: Let $DG'$ be the category of non unital dg algebras, and let $CoAlg'$ be the category of connected non-counital dg coalgebra, i.e each $C\in CoAlg'$ is the union of the kernels of the maps
$$
C\to C^{\otimes n}\quad n\geq 2
$$
wich are the compositions of the canonical projection with the iterated comultiplications on $C$. We denote with $\bar{\Omega}$ and $\bar{B}$ the reduced cobar and bar construction respectively. The functor $\bar{B}$ is well defined since for a non unital dg algebra $A$, its reduced bar construction $\bar{B}(A)$ is the non unital cotensor algebra $T^{+}(A[1])=\oplus_{n\geq 1}(A[1])^{\otimes n}$. A similar argument shows that $\bar{\Omega}$ is well defined.

1) Does it follows again that
$$
Hom_{DG'}(\bar{\Omega} C, A)\cong TW(C,A)\cong Hom_{Coalg'}(C, \bar{B}(A))?
$$
2)The functor $B$ preserves quasi isomorphisms between augmented dg algebras. What about $\bar{B}$?

3) The functor $\Omega$ preserves quasi isomorphisms between $2$-connected coaugmented coalgebras, what about $\bar{\Omega}$? Does $\bar{\Omega}$ sends graded quasi isomorphism to quasi isomorphism?

I think that most of the things here should follows by the equivalence of categories $A\to \bar{A}$ between augmented algebras and non unital algebras, but I don't know how to prove formally.